# UIView movement in window

Tags: ios, uiview, frame

I have some `UIView`. I know only about view. It can be added to `UIView`, `UIScrollView`, `UITableView`. But I want to detect when my view begin viewable and end viewable on screen (for example if view was added to `UIScrollView`).

[image: I have scroll view and add my view (banner) as subview]
I have scroll view and add my view (banner) as subview. But at first I can not see my banner and should scroll.

[image]
I want to detect moment when my view will show on screen.

Comment: Please explain question clearly...

Comment: I have uiview. This view was added to UIScrollView but was added on bottom. At first I can not see my view. But I want to detect moment when user begin to see view on screen. But I can work only with my view and can not work with UIScrollView.

Comment: Hey.. share your output screenshot and expected output screen shots...

Answer (score 0):

If I catched your point correctly, you may want to be notified at the moment the banner is visible during the scrolling of the `UIScrollView`. One solution is as following:

Firstly, It's you who add the banner as a subView of `UIScrollView`, so, you must know the `frame` of the banner.

Then, Comparing the `bannerView.frame.origin.y` and `scrollView.contentOffset.y`In the delegate method `- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView` of the ScrollView.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    BOOL becomingVisibleDuringScrollViewScrollDown = bannerView.frame.origin.y + CGRectGetHeight(bannerView.frame) == scrollView.contentOffset.y;
    BOOL becomingVisibleDuringScrollViewScrollUp = bannerView.frame.origin.y == scrollView.contentOffset.y + CGRectGetHeight(scrollView.frame);
    if (becomingVisibleDuringScrollViewScrollDown || becomingVisibleDuringScrollViewScrollUp) {
        // Banner become visible!
    }
}
```

---

**Old Answer**

You may implement your own class inherited from `UIView`，and override these methods to observe View-Related changes:

```
- (void)willMoveToSuperview:(UIView *)newSuperview;
- (void)didMoveToSuperview;
- (void)willMoveToWindow:(UIWindow *)newWindow;
- (void)didMoveToWindow;
```

And read this [Apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW90) for more information.

Comment: No. All of this methods work when we add view to superview. But my view was added and I want to detect moment when my view was shown (like viewWillAppear in UIViewController)

Comment: @Fess I edited my answer just now. Check it and see if I catch your point correctly.

Comment: I can not work with uiscrollview. I have library. And in my library I have only view. And I want to detect when my view appear on screen